# Calling stored procedure does not cause a row to be inserted into table

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, store

My stored procedure is:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ThemTram] 
(   
    @Ten nvarchar(50),
    @KhuVucID int,
    @TenTinh nvarchar(50),
    @TinhID int,
    @TenTram nvarchar(50)
)
AS
set @KhuVucID = (select KhuVuc.KhuVucID from KhuVuc where KhuVuc.Ten=@ten)
set @TinhID =(select Tinh.TinhID from Tinh Where (Tinh.TenTinh=@TenTinh and Tinh.KhuVucID=@KhuVucID))
if not exists (select Tram.TenTram from Tram where (Tram.TenTram=@TenTram and Tram.TinhID = @TinhID))
Begin
    insert into Tram(TenTram,TinhID) values (@TenTram,@TinhID)
end
```

and my c# program:

```
    private void ThemTramBT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string conn = "Data Source=USER-PC;Initial Catalog=NCKHmoi;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(conn);
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = connect;
        connect.Open();
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.CommandText = "ThemTram";
        command.Parameters.Add("@Ten", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = KhuVucComboBox.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@TenTinh", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = TinhComboBox.Text;
        command.Parameters.Add("@TenTram", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = ThemTramTB.Text;
        command.Dispose();
        connect.Close();
    }
```

but there is a probl. in the c# code. i can't insert a new data to it.
please help me.

Comment: you need command.ExecuteNonQuery() to insert

Answer (score 3):

You are not executing the command. As an aside you should really use `using` statements with the `SqlConnection` and (less importantly) `SqlCommand`:

```
private void ThemTramBT_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string conn = "Data Source=USER-PC;Initial Catalog=NCKHmoi;Integrated Security=True";
    using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(conn))
    {
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("ThemTram", conn))
        {
            connect.Open();
            command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            command.Parameters.Add("@Ten", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = KhuVucComboBox.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@TenTinh", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = TinhComboBox.Text;
            command.Parameters.Add("@TenTram", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50).Value = ThemTramTB.Text;

            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@KhuVucID", DBNull.Value); //need to pass even if not used
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TinhID", DBNull.Value); //need to pass even if not used
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Based on your comment it is not clear why your sproc is coded the way it is. I suggest you change it as below:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[ThemTram] 
(   
    @Ten nvarchar(50),
    @TenTinh nvarchar(50),
    @TenTram nvarchar(50)
)
AS

declare @KhuVucID int
declare @TinhID int

select @KhuVucID = KhuVuc.KhuVucID from KhuVuc where KhuVuc.Ten = @ten
select @TinhID = Tinh.TinhID from Tinh Where Tinh.TenTinh = @TenTinh and Tinh.KhuVucID = @KhuVucID

if not exists (select Tram.TenTram from Tram where Tram.TenTram = @TenTram and Tram.TinhID = @TinhID)
begin
    insert into Tram(TenTram, TinhID) values (@TenTram, @TinhID)
end
```

Comment: thank a lot. but, the program said that the@KhuVucID and @TinhID is not set.but in my database, KhuVucID and TinhID is primary key.

Comment: I see. If you need `@KhuVucID` and `@TinhID` as parameters to your sproc then they have to be supplied in your C# code. However, it is not clear why they are needed as inputs.

Comment: Because i got 3 different table, KHUVUC(TEN,KHUCVUCID), TINH(TENTINH,TINHID,KHUVUCID), TRAM(TENTRAM,TRAMID,TINHID). so, if i want to insert into TRAM, i need value TINHID to insert, but KHUVUCID and TINHID is not know, it is auto value. so, that's my problem. Thank for your help. i love u.^^

Comment: @VuNgoThanh OK. If the parameters are needed then I will edit the answer again.